# Unknown Android deployment JSON file location

Tags: android, json, qt

I tried to follow this example : http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-mobile-app-tutorial.html

But when I try to build it, I have this error :

> 23:51:49: Internal Error: Unknown Android deployment JSON file
>   location. Error while building/deploying project accelbubble (kit:
>   Android for armeabi (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.4.1)) When executing step "Build
>   Android APK

There is not a lot of things about this on the Internet, so I came here for help.

Anyone know what to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by installing QT on C:\Qt disk instead of D:\Program Files\Qt (my second hard drive, because the C is SSD and doesn't have much space).

Answer (score 5):

You need to select the run configuration for the project: see comments on [this Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-14075)

Select the 'Project' icon on the left toolbar, choose 'Run' on that active target, and the set "Run Configuration".

Comment: I am now testing on "calqlatr", the integrated example. And the Run configuration was already set at "calqlatr". I also tried to add "CONFIG += qtc_runnable" to the "calqlatr.pro" file, but I have the same error. Thanks for your answer, if you have more ideas i'll take them.

Comment: If this does not work because you are trying to compile a simple library (no application), check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31340092/3336423

Comment: This was my problem as well - I was getting the error because I had a Subdirs project with a dynamic library and an application, and the Run configuration was set to run the dynamic library project instead of the application. Thanks, your answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

My problem occured when I tried to build a library for Android.

I managed to solve it by removing corresponding records in `projectname.pro.user` file.

- Quit QtCreator
- remove the elements containing `apk` attribute and
  `install` attribute. Not the attributes, but the elements containing them
- run QtCreator and make sure there are no `build apk` and `install` steps in the project's build configuration

I also made sure there are no extra projectname.pro.user.* files and removed them, but I don't know if that matters.